# How to wait for ADB output in C#?

Tags: c#, android, windows, command-line, adb

I want to receive information from a `device` connected in `USB` via a C# program using `ADB` commands then flush the output.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "logcat -d -b main -v raw -s Command:I"; // get data in Log.I() with name == "Command"
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.Start();

string output;
do {
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("logcat -d -b main -v raw -s Command:I");
    output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
} while (output.Length < 1);

Console.WriteLine(output);

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("logcat -c"); // flush logcat

process.WaitForExit();
```

Doing that I understand that the program is constantly executing `adb logcat -d -b main -v raw -s Command:I`, isn't there a way to call a command one time and wait for the output?

I can do that in windows prompt using :

```
adb shell 'logcat -b main -v raw -s UNIQUE_TAG:I | (read -n 1 && kill -2 $((BASHPID-1)))'
```

but is this doable in C#?
Also the output doesn't seem to be flushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code below, we don't call `adb.exe` directly but through `cmd.exe` with a command waiting for any information log coming from logcat with the title "Command" : `adb shell logcat -b main -v raw -s Command:I`

```
private Process listeningProc;

public someClass(){
   listeningProc = new Process();
   listeningProc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   listeningProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   listeningProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   listeningProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   listeningProc.Start();

   listeningProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
       (s, e) => {
           if (e.Data == "SPECIFIC_COMMAND") {
               // do something
           }
       }
   );
   listeningProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

private void ListenToCommands(){
   listeningProc.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb shell logcat -b main -v raw -s Command:I"); //Listening for Info Logs titled "Command"

   while (true) { }
}
```

To flush logcat or send any command from the PC through ADB, I open another process and send the commands from there.

Edit:
You might want to add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //pause for 2 seconds` after each commands sent from the PC through `ADB` otherwise the device sometimes doesn't execute all commands when sent successively too quickly

Answer (score 1):

You can't read to the end more than once; `ReadToEnd` ultimately means "until the pipe is closed and I've consumed everything, and no more data will *ever ever* arrive". `ReadToEnd` will also never finish until `adb.exe` either *intentionally* signals that it is done writing (and will never write again), or terminates - so this is why you aren't getting as far as flushing.

What you *can* do is read (a byte/character at a time, if needed) until you have, say, a single line - so if the expectation here is "one command in, one line out" then it is simple enough. If there isn't a way of knowing how many lines will come back, then you would usually use two threads, and have a dedicated reader thread that takes data from the `process.StandardOutput` (byte/character at a time, or line by line) and does whatever is needed with it.

Comment: The expectation is only to listen until a single line comes from the device. I've taken your advice and modified ReadToEnd() with ReadLine() then with Read() but in both cases it still doesn't seem to get as far as flushing

Comment: @JosB well, does `logcat` ever return an empty line? because an empty line is the only way your `do` loop exits. Note that EOF is not the same as an empty line, and if the output terminates *after* a line-feed, I would expect to receive `null` from the final `ReadToEnd`, so: you might want to watch out for that. Ultimately, to debug this, I'd write the outputs from `adb` somewhere, including making `null` obvious; does it ever stop? does it return an empty line? does it return `null`? I don't know - but these are things you should check for

Answer (score 0):

This is how i used to code for such things
Here is my code Hope u understand it

```
  //to run the all the cmd,adb.fastboot.exe command using these function
   //here in startfunc pass the .exe file u want to execute,Arguments which u want to pass 
    //string msg = It is nothing Extra message if u want to add to your final output


    private static string Execute(string Startfunc, String Arguments,string msg)
    {   
        string text = null;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = Startfunc;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;         
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Start(); 
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            text += output;
            string err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            text += err;
        }
        while (!p.HasExited);
        text += msg;
        return text;
    }

     //now i will call above function and make it wait until we get the result

     private void normal_reboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        
            txt_Log.Text = "rebooting" +Environment.NewLine;
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                txt_Log.Text=Execute("adb.exe","reboot","Done");
            });
            do { Application.DoEvents(); } while (!t.IsCompleted);                                    
    }
```

Comment: I ... don't think this code works the way you think it works; using `ReadToEnd` in a `do`/`while` loop doesn't make sense; I think this code is working mostly by accident (and it looks like it creates a hot loop if an application ever closes both `stdout` and `stderr` but *stays running*)

Answer (score 0):

You can also look for output/error messages asyncly. So you don't need a (blocking) loop:
This example just outputs the messages, but can be extended by full methods

```
p.OutputDataReceived+= (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
p.BeginOutputReadLine();//This is important, otherwise the event won't be fired
p.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

This should print every line received by adb